# Definition of exponential function

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have no knowledge of the value of $e$

You are interested in characterizing the functions $F = \{f \in \mathbb{R^{\mathbb{R}}}: f' = f\}$

It isn't too hard to show that if $f \in F$, such that $f > 0$ somewhere, then $f > 0$ everywhere and $f$ is a monotonically increasing function. Additionally, $f \in F \implies af \in F, a \in \mathbb{R}$, by the chain rule. Thus, if $\exists f \in F$ with $f>0$, then $\exists g\in F$ with $g(0) = 1$.

**Q:** How can we show $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$

Comment: How do you define $\kappa^x$ without any knowledge of $\exp$ or $\ln$?

Comment: As @MathematicsStudent1122 says, it is meaningless to "show $g(x) = \kappa^x$ for some real $\kappa$" without having an actual definition of exponential functions on $\mathbf R$ already.   However, if we accept that there is a solution $E(x)$ that does not vanish anywhere then it's easy to show all solutions are multiples of $E(x)$: if $F'(x) = F(x)$ for all $x$ then consider $Q(x) = F(x)/E(x)$. We have $Q' = (EF' - FE')/E^2 = (EF - FE)/E^2 = 0$, so $Q$ is constant. Set $c$ to be that constant, so $F(x) = cE(x)$ for all real $x$.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 Very good point. Let me rewrite that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have some general theory of power series, you can show that $\sum_n x^n/n!$ converges everywhere to a function $\exp(x)$ that satisfies $dy/dx=y$.

Since the differential equation is linear, therefore,
$$ g(x) = f(x)- \exp(x) $$
satisfies the same differential equation, and is $0$ for $x=0$.

You have already proved that this prevents $g$ from being positive anywhere. Likewise, this prevents $g$ from being *negative* anywhere, so $g$ is identically zero, and $f(x)=\exp(x)$.

---

To justify the notation $e^x$:

Once you know (by the above argument) that the differential equation has a unique solution, you can prove that $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$ -- namely, for fixed $y$, the function $x\mapsto \frac{1}{\exp(y)}\exp(x+y)$ satisfies $f'=f$ and $f(0)=1$, and it must therefore equal $\exp(x)$.

We can now, by induction and a bit of busywork to handle signs, prove
$$ \exp(x)^n = \exp(nx) $$
for arbitrary $n\in\mathbb Z$, and then
$$ \exp(x)^{n/m} = \exp(\tfrac nm x) $$

Finally, setting $x$ to $1$ and defining $e=\exp(1)$ yields
$$ e^q = \exp(q) $$
for all $q\in\mathbb Q$.

If we have already defined irrational powers of positive reals by requiring continuity, this ensures $e^x = \exp(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$ (because $\exp$ is differentiable and therefore continuous). Otherwise, define $b^x=\exp(x\exp^{-1}(b))$ and we see that this agrees with the algebraic definition of *rational* powers and is continuous in both $b$ and $x$ for $b>0$.

Comment: Hey. Sorry for the late response - went on vacation :) Great response! It will take me a little bit to digest. I'll comment if I have more questions :) Appreciate the thoughtful answer

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

we have $$\forall x\in \Bbb R \;\;g'(x)=g (x) \;\;g (0)=1$$

By Cauchy-Lipschitz, there is only one solution.

we check easily that
$$x\mapsto 1+x+\frac {x^2}{2!}+... $$
has an infinite radius of convergence and it satisfies the conditions above.

Comment: This looks as if this proves the statement, but it does not. It is well known that there are functions which are infinitely often differentiable and have a convergent Taylor series in a given point, but such that the Taylor series does not equal the function. You either need to show that a solution of $f^\prime = f$ is analytic in a neighbourhood of $x=0$ or that the power series solves the differential equation.

Comment: ...(and a solution to the differential equation is unique for given initial conditions).